# Area of Fill region in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, polygon, shapes, fill, area

I am building a program in vb which calculate the area of arbitary shape,I used graphics.drawing to draw the closed curve and i filled using fill .Since using 'fill' will fill any closed loop in my drawing figure,I am thinking maybe it is possible to find approximate area of closed figure with help of 'Fill',Is there any way to do this in visual basic? Thank you

Comment: I think this can be done by using a [**GraphicsPath**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I searched in GraphicsPath class,But couldn't find any reference to the area,Is there any other class which deal with this?

Comment: Don't think so. But there's not really a reference to the area. You construct the GraphicsPath and draw to it, then I think you call [**`Graphics.FillPath()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fillpath(v=vs.110).aspx) to fill the entire drawing. -- You see, a `GraphicsPath` only contains information about _where to draw_. It doesn't actually draw anything until you call `Graphics.DrawPath()` or `Graphics.FillPath()`.

Comment: I see you tagged this with polygon, which are not completely arbitrary. Convex polygons can always be broken into a set of triangles. The areas of the triangles can be calculated and summed. If polygons are not always convex, then this probably gets more complicated.